# How to create multiple project template in one solution for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

in the normal wp7 app, there is only one project. I try to add another project into an existing solution. however, it could not run. I think it is possible to add more than one project templates into existing solution. But I just dont know what need to be done or what files need to be deleted. woud appreciate your help on this.

----- Update ---

1. Create two projects;  ProjMain and ProjChild
2. In projChild, add a new Page and delete App.xaml, MainPage.Xaml,AppManifest.xml, WMAppManifest.xml, ApplicationIcon.png, Background.png

3 In ProjMain, I add ProjChild into this ProjMain.

Comment: This question, it lacks.  "However, it could not run."  Nowhere near enough information.  Did you get some kind of message like "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add multiple projects under a solution. To the main project you want to build, you need to add references of the other projects to it. Each project, however, needs to be error free and compile on its own. Check the build output for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can switch one project to another. We have a need to add reference of that project.
then use NavigationService like.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AnotherProject;component/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

here  AnotherProject is second project from where we want to use new page and page name.